# Session Storage not saving

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

I have a button which changes the background colour, and I want to save the colour to local storage so it is the same when the page is refreshed. Using console.log(field.value), I can see that my function is adding the new colour to local storage, however when the page is refreshed the session storage seems to be empty and the background colour is not the same as before it was refreshed.

```js
class DrumKit {
  constructor() {
    this.backgroundColor = document.querySelector('body');
  }

  saveSessionColor() {
    let field = this.backgroundColor;
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentColor', JSON.stringify(this.backgroundColor.style.background));
    let x = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentColor'));
    field.value = x;
  }
}
drumKit.themeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drumKit.saveSessionColor();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML part too?

Comment: This looks syntactically invalid. `saveSessionColor` does not appear to be a class method.

Comment: Oh sorry, the way I typed it in here makes it look like that but in my js file it is within the class. I am quite new to js though so I presume I making a fairly obvious error that I just can't spot.

Comment: Couple things. You have a variable called "backgroundColor" that is a reference to an element. You should call it "bodyEl" or something. However, you don't need that at all because the body element already has a special persistent reference, called `document.body`, at all times. Next, you create the `field` variable, but don't use it on the next line. You do use it later, but `field` is just another reference to `document.body`. It doesn't have a `value`. You can add `value`, but it won't do anything. You need, on page load, to set the body element's background style.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle because this didn't work in the snippet editor

This gets the session color on save, which avoids the context issues

https://jsfiddle.net/9zwef8ht/2/

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #ddd; /* default value */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
"use strict";
class DrumKit {
  constructor(id) {
    // set up the button ... ?
    this.themeBtn = document.getElementById(id);
    // if the button exists, add a click handler
    if (this.themeBtn !== null) {
      this.themeBtn.addEventListener('click', this.saveSessionColor);
    }
    // clear the current color 
    sessionStorage.removeItem('currentColor');
  }

  saveSessionColor() {
    // get the style
    // thanks to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null);
    let backgroundColor = style.backgroundColor;
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentColor', backgroundColor);
  }

  setSessionColor() {
    let color = sessionStorage.getItem('currentColor');
    // if currentColor is set
    if (color !== null) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    } else {
      // otherwise ...
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    }
  }
}
let drumKit = new DrumKit("go");

// use a button to check the code, remove before launch
document.getElementById("check").addEventListener('click', drumKit.setSessionColor);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I have tried to implement it in my project and on the console log I can see that the colour is being saved to session storage, but when the page refreshes the background colour is back to the default value instead of the one before I refreshed it. How can I change this?

Comment: You might want to use localStorage instead of sessionStorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API - sessionStorage lasts for the session, localStorage lasts until you clear it